# Chat Script with PHP/MySQL like Facebook

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, chat

I am currently developing a PUBLIC and OPEN SOURCE ecommerce software and want to embed a chat plugin into it using PHP/MySQL (similar to Facebook). But much simpler. You can see the draft preview below.

[image: Preview of chat script]

**Functions:**

- Send and recieve messages (only friends)
- Add / Search / Remove / Block Friends

Security is important issue, because this chat plugin would be embedded into software and that software will be published as OPEN SOURCE.

My question is that where should I **get down** to writing it and how to get **good security**?

Comment: You think you have problems with security in a chat application and you want to write an ecommerce solution? Good luck... :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is not your question.. But php/apache is not the best solution for chatting. You'd have to poll(make requests) frequently, and that is something that just cannot scale in the php/apache environment. I would recommend you to look for another server/platform on the side for just the chat application. Read up about comet programming and have a look at node.js

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend Google Code to host your project. This is the Version Control system that will look after your code, and allow 3rd party people to help you for free.

Good security always comes with a bug/issue tracker for the project, which I think Google Code also gives you.

Tell us where you host it here please, with a URL. I for one will want to help out.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I didn't finish yet, but if you give me your email I will be happy to share URL and my ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using an ajax chat rather going the php route.

I found a good one googling a bit

https://blueimp.net/ajax/

I don't know, maybe it works for you, it really depends on what features you want.